# Roles y Permisos a Usuarios

Tags: c#, sql-server, directorioactivo

Buenas tardes compañeros, tengo algunos problemas en los cuales espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo un sitio web(Sitio web vació c#) en el cual hago la autenticación mediante las credenciales de mi AD.

1.-¿Como puedo asignar roles a mis usuarios? es decir que al momento de logearse solo vean los menús correspondientes a su perfil. Leí sobre ASP.NET Identity y Sobre System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagment pero la verdad no se cual me funcione mejor, si tienen algún ejemplo de como utilizar alguno de estos se los agradecería.

2.- No tengo tabla de usuarios ya que el sistema autentifica con el AD, lo que he pensado es hacer una tabla de usuarios y que la contraseña sea la misma que la del AD así que si cambian la contraseña de usuario en mi AD se actualice en mi base de datos, ¿Como puedo hacer esto?

Desde ya muchas gracias.